# How do I get the value in a Google Sheets cell and test its contents against a range of cells?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to speed up my workflow.  Typically I enter the CPU of a computer we are selling and then look up its speed and core count etc.  But I want to have this information auto-fill as I record the CPU (based on information I have already put into another sheet).

How can I get the value of a particular cell so I can test it against my pre-recorded CPU's?

In Python I'm looking for something like this..

```
    Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    if Spreadsheet.currentSheet == 'sheet1':
        active_cell = Spreadsheet.GetActiveCell()
        if active_cell.value != None:
            cpu = cell.value
            row = active_cell.getRow()

            if cpu in Spreadsheet.Sheet2.cellRange(B2:B1000):
                row2 = row matching cpu
                Spreadsheet.sheet1.cell( E, row).value = Spreadsheet.Sheet2.cell( C, row2 ).value
                Spreadsheet.sheet1.cell( F, row).value = Spreadsheet.Sheet2.cell( D, row2 ).value
```

This is what I have currently..

```
function onEdit() {
   var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  // current Spreadsheet Document?
   if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) {           
      var active_cell = s.getActiveCell();  
      if( active_cell != null ) {
    }
  }
}
```

I believe the above code is checking if the cell itself doesn't exist.  How do I proceed to get the contents of the cell?

How can I test that value against the range of cells?

Also, is the line `var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` referencing the entire document or sheet1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` return the active `Sheet`. If you want the `Spreadhseet` you should use `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`.

Then, in order to access the content of a cell, you must first specify its `Range`. For instance, if you want all the cells of the sheet you can do : `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()`, it will return an array of rows (each row contains as cells as columns in your sheet). If you want a specific cell you can do it via the `getRange(...)` methods (documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer))).

**EDIT : Adding active cell details**

And if you want to access the active cell value, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue()` would suffice.

Comment: Ok thank you.  So to get the value in the current cell it would be `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue()` ?